# Thrust method for an asteroids duplicate Java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, motion

I have a project that is similar to the Asteroids game. The game contains a thrust method, which like the name suggests thrusts the spaceship. The method is not thrusting in the direction I am asking to. The spaceship will rotate with the left and right keys and will thrust with the space key.

```
  private static final double THRUST_VALUE = 3;
  private static final int MAX_SPEED = 4;
  private int lives;
  private int rotationSpeed;

 public void thrust() {
double[] newVelocity = new double[2];
double[] oldVelocity = getVelocity();
newVelocity[0] = oldVelocity[0] - THRUST_VALUE * Math.sin(getRotation()*Math.PI/180);
newVelocity[1] = oldVelocity[1] - THRUST_VALUE * Math.cos(getRotation()*Math.PI/180);
System.out.println(newVelocity[0]);
System.out.println(newVelocity[1]);
if (newVelocity[0] >= MAX_SPEED || newVelocity[0] <= -MAX_SPEED){
  newVelocity[0] = MAX_SPEED;
}
if (newVelocity[1] >= MAX_SPEED || newVelocity[1] <= -MAX_SPEED){
  newVelocity[1] = MAX_SPEED;
}
setVelocity(newVelocity);
```

The properties for the velocity and the rotation are inherited from a Polygon class. Here are the properties being declared:

```
private Point[] shape;   // An array of points.
  private Point position;   // The offset mentioned above.
  private double rotation; // Zero degrees is due east.
```

The code runs fine, but the logic of the code is off and it is not listening to the position, but I don't know what the issue is. All input is appreciated.

Comment: First, the move tag doesnt do what you think it does. To check, draw a line in your space ship that shows where the ship would thrust if you pushed the space button. That would test if the thrust is going where you think it is.

Comment: 1. You did not share code that actually updates position! However thrust is acceleration so it should be applied to it `acc = thrust` then speed `vel += acc*dt` and then position `pos += vel*dt` where `dt` is the interval you are updating this in seconds (or whatever). You can rotate like this too `eps = turn_thrust; omg += eps*dt; ang += omg*dt; ` 2. Your max speed limit is wrong (not handling signed values correctly). 3. you are applying the thrust in opposite direction? 4. is you angle direction matching your coordinate system? 5. you are mixing `int` and `double` for clearly float values